# SPSS logistic regression - Exp(B) displays reciprocal of my categorical vars?

Tags: logistic-regression, spss

I'm performing logistical regression with SPSS and Exp(B) is showing the reciprocal of what I'd like. E.g., where I'd like to display, say 2.0, Exp(B) is listed as 0.5. My variables are all categorical, so the coding is arbitrary.

I know I can recode variables, but I'm wondering if there's a simple setting in one of the dialogs to display reciprocals or recode on the fly? If possible, I'd like to do it through the UI rather than the command line input?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the LOGISTIC REGRESSION procedure (Analyze>Regression>Binary Logistic in the menus), clicking on the Categorical button will allow you to specify predictor variables as categorical and the desired type of contrast coding for each one. As long as the variables of interest are binary or the contrasts you want use either the first or last level of the variables as the reference category in forming the contrasts, you can specify them in that dialog box in order to get what you want.

If a variable has more than two levels and you want to use a category other than the first or the last as the reference category, you'd have to paste the command from the dialogs and add the sequential number of the desired category to the CONTRAST subcommand for that predictor variable. For example, if you have a three-category variable named X and you want to compare the first and third categories against the second one, you'd edit it to read

/CONTRAST (X)=Indicator(2)

or

/CONTRAST (X)=Simple(2)

depending on the type of contrasts specified in the dialogs (these two would produce the same results for these contrasts in models where X is not contained in an interaction term also in the model, differing only in how the constant or intercept is represented).